# Two random variables X and Y follow the same distribution. Then

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ follow the same distribution.

Then

1. The distribution of $X − Y$ must be symmetric about $0$.
2. The median of $X − Y$ must be zero.
3. The median of $X + Y$ is twice of the median of $X$.
4. The mean of $X − Y$ , if finite, must be $0$.
5. None of the above is correct.

It is a very short question, and I think the answer is Number $5$, isn't it?

Comment: Could you provide your reason?

Comment: Can more than one answers be correct?

Comment: Only can choose 1 answer

Comment: Are you sure that the last one is "none of the above" and not the opposite "all of the above are correct"? Because $X-Y$ and $-(X-Y)=Y-X$ have the same distribution, so 1. is correct. But also $E[X]=E[Y]$ so $E[X-Y]E[X]-E[Y]=0$ so 4. is also correct. Similarly 2. is also correct and I did not check 3.

Comment: @Jimmy $X$ and $Y$ could be dependent, hence $4$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=Y$ then 1,2,3,4 would be correct.  In particular $X-Y=0$ with probability $1$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then 1,2,4 are correct but 3 might not be.  For example, suppose $X$ takes the value $1$ with probability $0.4$ and the value $0$ with probability $0.6$

But if $X$ and $Y$ have a more complicated relationship then there is little you can say about distributions and medians.  For example if $(X,Y) = (0,1)$, $(1,4)$ or $(4,0)$ each with probability $\frac13$. You are left with linearity of expectation and assertion 4.